# CSS won't link to HTML File

Tags: html, css

For some odd reason, I can't link my CSS file to my HTML file. When I attempt to view the changes, I don't see any change. I have looked to see what I have done wrong, but I can't figure it out.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "styles.css" type = "text/css">
        <title>Azul's Tech</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 title = "Azul's Tech">Azul's Tech</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}

h1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Where is styles.css, in relation to the html file?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Style.css is in the exact same directory as index.html.

Comment: Maybe your webserver has a very strong caching strategy and thus there will no new version be used. If you directly open the CSS file in the browser, is it up-to-date?

Comment: Double-check the spelling of your css file. I don't know if the spaces make any difference, or the ordering of elements, but try this just in case:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

Comment: Some browsers cache extremely aggressively as well. I hate IE for cache long dead pages! Be sure to force a refresh using Ctrl + F5 if you are testing updates in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`href = "styles.css"`

1. Did you put css file and html file in the same folder?
2. Check the name of your css file; is it really "styles.css"?

Comment: I just came to realize my silly mistake. The file was actually titled style.css. Sadly HTML doesn't report errors like other languages.

Comment: I often do that too :D

Comment: I was attempting to jump from Python to HTML/CSS and forgot that neither HTML or CSS offered error reports if something went wrong.

Comment: it's little bit tricky to debug html/css. so, I think 'trial & error' is the best thing that we can do

Comment: And not having twitchy fingers when typing.